# How do you describe the sound of an old computer?

Tags: word-request

The kind in the 90s with a giant CRT monitors and noisy hard disks & fans. I think "buzz" and "hum" are not loud enough because nowadays laptops still hum when overheated. But I don't know a stronger word. Thanks for any help!

Comment: My new mini-tower computer with its hot CPU and three cooling fans is far noisier than those old-school computers from the 1990s, when the bearings on the fans begin to fail. But there is far less vibration from the modern solid state hard drive! :-) The 6-inch floppy drives made a clicking and clunking sound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider *whir*, which [Collins](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/whir) defines as:

> **whir** (or **whirr**) (*n.*) a prolonged soft swish or buzz, as of a motor working

Another possibility is *drone*. The word *drone* has many meanings, but it can be used as a noun or a verb to describe the noises you mention. From [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/drone):

> **drone** (*n.*) a continuous low humming or buzzing sound
>
> **drone** (*v.*) to produce a low-pitched hum or buzz

As a side note, I'm not sure I agree that *buzz* is "not loud enough," because buzzing covers a wide spectrum of noises, some of them rather loud:

> Though we spotted tracks, we saw very little wildlife; the buzz of the machine tended to scare animals away.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2001/01/28/AR2005041401850.html): Snowmobiling Mont Tremblant, Quebec, by Ben Abramson, special to *The Washington Post*, Sunday, January 28, 2001</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the words: *whirr, drone, buzz, hum* describe the nature of the sound - but don't say much about its volume. You could opt for a word that is less descriptive but implies loudness like "clatter", or you could use hyperbole (which is a tendency of many US native speakers) as in: "That old computer sounds like a helicopter."